# If user selects files, how do I remove previously selected files from db?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a select box where users can choose files they want to be attached to their system. Each of the files that get selected are inserted into the database. However, if they unselect that file, I want it's row removed from the database.

Without removing all the files attached to that user on that system and reinserting the now-selected files, how would I remove the previously-selected files that are no longer needed?

```
<select name="choose_files[]" class="multi-select" multiple="" id="attach_files">
<?php
  foreach ($files AS $file) { 
    echo '<option value="' . $file['id'] . '"';
    if ($file['id'] === $compared['file_id']) 
    { echo ' SELECTED';}
  }
   echo '>' . $file['originalFilename'] . '</option>';
  } ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: You should also post your 'update' function which handles this form.

Comment: Update/delete function not built yet, that code was given as an illustration in case my description was too vague.

Comment: You have to send something to the server, otherwise nothing is going to change. In the php code you can then compare the sent list with the list of *files* in the database. After that you can delete the identified rows.

Comment: Basically, grab a list of the previous list, on submit, delete the files from previous list, then insert the new ones?

Comment: File-size and a HASH could give you a clue if a file is one you already have or not.  (Probably would be calculating those on the client and sending up rather than the files themselves)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/array_diff). For example:

```
$current_files = get_current_files();
$post_files = $_POST['choose_files'];

$remove = array_diff($current_files, $post_files);
$add = array_diff($post_files, $current_files);

if (!empty($remove)) {
    // remove these files from DB
}

if (!empty($add)) {
    // add these files to DB
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my variables were in reverse in my code - so my array_diff was behaving like $add instead of $remove, and vice versa.